# Mac OS X & RDC: the terminal server has exceeded the maximum number of allowed connections

Tags: macos

I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac. When I try to  connect to a remote server, it shows an error: `the terminal server has exceeded the maximum number of allowed connections`.

So how can I connect to the remote server without this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `/console` at the end of the server name or IP.

Reference: http://www.lai18.com/content/1976601.html